# Question on URL redirection for wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

So long I had installed wordpress blog on my domain which points to url like this

http://www.domainname.com/xxxx/blogs/

Now that I have shifted to new hosting, I had set up the blog in the following way

http://www.domainname.com/blog

The search engines have indexed my earlier url as i see the same when I search in search engines.

Is there any easy way to redirect from old url to new url.

thanks in advance

Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put up a .htaccess file and set it up for redirection. The .htaccess file will be in your public_html.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/XXXX/blogs/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R]
```

This should doo...

Comment: I am new to this. Could you give me any more tips on this? thanks alot